# My x-axis is messed up for huge datasets?

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, data-visualization

I am trying to plot a countplot using Seaborn library. The data-set is a huge dataset with lots of data of more than 100,000 entries and 67 columns. I have tried plotting it and my x-axis gets messed up. I have tried to increase the figure-size of the plot but still it does not work for me. My code and figure of the plot is as follows:

```
#We will see what is the status of columns that have null values or comprise of values that are zero
na = pd.DataFrame(df.isnull().sum())
plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
sns.barplot(y=na[0],x=na.index)
plt.xlabel(xlabel=na.index)
plt.title("Columns with Null Values Distribution",size=20)
```

[image: The plot is basically a count-plot of covids-information data-set. It consists of more than 100,000 entries and 67 columns.]

Any suggestion to plot in such a way that the x-axis gets more clearer and is easily being able to be visualised would be helpful. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So I have basically found the solution to this question and that basically is by swapping x-axis and y-axis. I also have amended my code to use dpi as well. The code which gives me proper visualisation is as follows:
#We will see what is the status of columns that have null values or comprise of values that are zero

```
na = pd.DataFrame(df.isnull().sum())
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(20,18), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='r')
sns.barplot(y=na.index,x=na[0])
#plt.xlabel(xlabel=na.index)
plt.title("Columns with Null Values Distribution",size=10)
```

The visualisation is as follows:
[image]